# Magento 2 - Programmatically Check Magento Version (CE / EE)

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2.1, magento-community, magento-core

Does anyone know the best way a module can check if it is being executed on Magento 2 Enterprise Edition and which exact version number is being used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to inject `\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface` into your constructor.

```
protected $productMetadata;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata,
    ...
) {
    $this->productMetadata = $productMetadata;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```

Then you can get current Magento version by (assuming that `ProductMetadataInterface` object is assigned to `$productMetadata` field):

`$version = $this->productMetadata->getVersion();`

And edition (Community/Enterprise) by:

`$edition = $this->productMetadata->getEdition();`

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

**Use Magento standard way to get version of your site, 
Using Block - Template way is proper way to do call any function in magento 2,**

Inside Block file,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block
class Version extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{

protected $_productMetadata;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
        $this->_productMetadata = $productMetadata;
    }

    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->_productMetadata->getVersion();
    }
}
```

inside `template` file,

```
echo $block->getVersion();
```

**Using Direct Objectmanager is not proper way to use in magento 2,**

```
  $objManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $magentoVersion = $objManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
  echo $magentoVersion->getVersion();
```